# Click once deployment: Downloading XXX.manifest did not succeed. (404) Not Found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, clickonce

One of our customers is having and issue updating their ClickOnce application after the deployment of a new version (upgrade from version 2 to version 3).

First of all, when he ran the application, it didn't seem to detect that a new version had been deployed. Later on, after downloading manually the latest AssemblyName.application file from the Application Server (from the URL the application has been published to) he got the following error where, for some reason, it seems to keep looking for the old deployment (which doesn't exist anymore because it's been replaced by the new). The "funny" thing is that we've installed this version from different machines & locations and it has worked fine for everybody except the 2 guys "behind that proxy". This is the error message they're getting:

---

```
ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of example.com/YYY/Client/AppName.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading example.com/YYY/Client/Application Files/AppName_2_0_0_0/AppName.exe.manifest did not succeed.
        + The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.


ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    [22/03/2016 08:59:18] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading example.com/YYY/Client/Application Files/AppName_2_0_0_0/AppName.exe.manifest did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.

DETAILED EXECUTION FLOW
...
[08:59:14] : DownloadQueueItem :  _sourceUri = example.com/YYY/Client/AppName.application,  _targetPath = D:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\Deployment\MCX7AOC4.6KW\7E3KZCJY.P28.application
[08:59:16] : HttpWebRequest= Proxy.IsByPassed=False, ProxyUri=http://BLAproxy.BLA.com:8080/
[08:59:17] : HttpWebResponse=ResponseUri=example.com/YYY/Client/AppName.application
[08:59:17] : Method Call : ManifestReader.FromDocumentNoValidation(D:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\Deployment\MCX7AOC4.6KW\7E3KZCJY.P28.application) called.
[08:59:17] : expectedAppId=example.com/YYY/Client/AppName.application#AppName.application, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0e37c329267e5e4f, processorArchitecture=msil/AppName.exe, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0e37c329267e5e4f, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32
[08:59:17] : Reparse the deployment manifest for validations.
[08:59:17] : Method Call : ManifestReader.FromDocument(D:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\Deployment\MCX7AOC4.6KW\7E3KZCJY.P28.application) called.
[08:59:17] : Schema validation passed.
[08:59:17] : Manifest is parsed successfully.
[08:59:17] : Semantic validation passed.
[08:59:18] : Signature validation passed.
[08:59:18] : Method Call : FollowDeploymentProviderUri called.
[08:59:18] : Deployment manifest zone is not local machine. Zone = Internet
[08:59:18] : providerUri=example.com/YYY/Client/AppName.application,sourceUri=example.com/YYY/Client/AppName.application
[08:59:18] : Deployment provider not followed.
[08:59:18] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
[08:59:18] : Could not find application in store. Continue with downloading application manifest.
[08:59:18] : Method Call : InstallApplication called.
[08:59:18] : Method Call : DownloadApplication called.
[08:59:18] : Start processing application manifest.
[08:59:18] : Method Call : DownloadApplicationManifest called.
[08:59:18] : Method Call : DownloadManifest called.
[08:59:18] : Method Call : DownloadManifestAsRawFile called.
[08:59:18] : Method Call : DownloadSingleFile called
[08:59:18] : DownloadQueueItem :  _sourceUri = example.com/YYY/Client/Application Files/AppName_2_0_0_0/AppName.exe.manifest,  _targetPath = D:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\Deployment\YLJO3ZJO.CAB\T2LP22AQ.EZX\AppName.exe.manifest
[08:59:18] : HttpWebRequest= Proxy.IsByPassed=False, ProxyUri=http://BLAproxy.BLA.com:8080/
```

---

Does anybody have an idea of what might have occurred? We have some suspicions but, as I wouldn't like to condition your answers, I won't mention them for now.

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case it can help anybody in the future: it ended up being an issue with the proxy that was cacheing an old version of the Application Deployment Manifest.

Besides, uninstalling the application (from the Control Panel) & deleting the ClickOnce file cache (%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0*.*) as described in the following link has helped fixing many issues in the past as well: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2713442

Hope this can help somebody someday...

Comment: There are a couple of other ways to quickly clear the cache too. - run `mage -cc ` (which is part of the SDK - same as `sn`). If you don't have the SDK installed you can use  `rundll32 %windir%\system32\dfshim.dll CleanOnlineAppCache`. Also with XBAPs  Use this in your AssemblyInfo file: `AssemblyVersion="1.0.0.0"`. If you use asterisks like this "1.0.*", it'll keep incrementing version and you'll get a new version with each click!

Comment: For me it was a case of Windows VM using Chrome as a default app to launch. And I couldn't have Chrome as a Default browser, since the association of Default App (Start->System->Settings->Default Apps -> Choose default app by file type -> .xbap was Windows Presentation Foundation Host... So I had to change my default browser to IE (Firefox would have worked too if I had it on the VM). Then Visual Studio launched correct browser.

Comment: @Natxo, Removing (%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0*.*) will lose the personalized data. Not good approach, should find another way. Replied to Microsoft as well, for the limitation of this suggested answer.